# Algo estilo setInterval para PHP

Tags: php, laravel-5.5

Existe alguma função no PHP que agende determinada rotina? O que eu gostaria é que ao virar o dia, no caso, 00:00h, um script, em php, fosse disparado para executar determinada tarefa. Seria mais ou menos o setInterval do javascript, onde a cada tempo é executado algo. No meu exemplo, quero que sempre quando trocar o dia, o script seja executado pesquisando algumas informações no banco e alterando essas informações conforme a necessidade previamente estabelecida.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Diferente de um código em `Js`, o código em `PHP` "morre" depois da requisição. Ou seja, não é possível/viável realizar algo como o `setTimeout` ou `setInterval`.

A melhor solução para esses casos é utilizar um agendador de tarefas, no *Unix*, utilize o [**crontab**](https://linux.die.net/man/1/crontab).

No [laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel), você pode utilizar a biblioteca [**Schedule**](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Console/Scheduling/Schedule.html) e [**CallbackEvent**](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Console/Scheduling/CallbackEvent.html) para lhe auxilar com o agendamento de scripts.

Ex:

```
/* Agendar para executar o script a meia-noite. */
Schedule::call(function() {
    /* Code Here */
})->daily();
```

> O `Laravel` utiliza a biblioteca [cron-expression](https://github.com/mtdowling/cron-expression) como base.

Comment: Mto obrigado, Valdeir.